# How to develop compiler without compiler writing tools

Tags: compiler-construction

My teacher gave this question ( how to develop compilers without compiler writing tools ). I searched for it but I did not find anything. So, If anyone have any idea about this please help me. I found so many information about developing compiler with writing tools but I found nothing when I searched for without compiler writing tools.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is off-topic, but I was going to say "the dragon book", but then [found this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25840/222560).

Comment: You always can use machine codes

Comment: @close-voters How is this 'too broad'? Please explain. Perfectly simple question with perfecly simple and well-known answer.

Comment: @KenY-N The post you linked to is ridiculous. The book is a standard teaching text. There are others, but, as one respondent stated, it is completely bizarre that a meta post was created to try to censor this one.

Comment: OMG Two more unexplained close votes. If you don't know anything about compilers, please stay out of this, and if you do and still want to close-vote, please provide your reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

1. Hand-written scanner (large `switch` statement), and
2. Recursive descent parser.

Comment: what are the advantage and disadvantage of using these two methods?

Comment: @GhezlanAL-Nofly The advantage of using tools such as lex/yacc is that it simplifies writing the lexical analysis and parsing stages and you can get up to speed quickly. The disadvantage is that it is hard to get reasonable error reporting from generated parsers. There can also be problems expressing the grammar of the source language in the formal model used by the parser generator. 
A very simplistic view is that parser generators are best used for simple domain-specific languages in homebrewn tools while compilers for complete programming languages usually have hand-written parsers.

Comment: @Ghezian *Now* you're too broad. There is no particular advantage except that you don't need generator tools, and the disadvantage is that you have to write miles of code instead of having the generator write it for you, and with guaranteed correctness.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler is basically a filter/converter. It reads text files and outputs data that happens to be identical to the instructions the given CPU understands.

So you need to find out:

- what assembler code your source language‘s commands are equivalent to
- what byte sequences each of these assembler commands are equivalent to

Then you can read the source file and output compiled code.

Comment: I would appreciate if whoever down-voted this could give an explanation why?

Comment: Certainly. 1. A compiler consists essentially of a NFA or DFA plus a DPDA plus semantic checking and actions plus code generation and optimization. 2. There is no '*happens* to be' about it. That is what a compiler is *for*. 3. There is nothing in this waffle that answers the question in any way, or that betrays the least understanding of the topic.

Comment: That's an interesting assumption, given I've written several programming languages and compilers so far. Consider that I might be trying to reduce the answer to a concept a beginner may understand and be familiar with.

Comment: It's not an assumption, it's a fact. Whatever your understanding of the process may be, it is not reflected in this answer, which doesn't address the question that was asked in any way. He is asking how to write a compiler without a scanner & parser generator. Not for some pointless waffle.